# Unable to get data from from inner class

Tags: java, android, oop, android-asynctask, inner-classes

I have a Inner class which extends AsyncTask inside my main class

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
String variable;
public onCreate(){

    onClickListener{
    new InnerClass().execute(params);
    variable // Here the value is always null
    }
}

class InnerClass extends AsyncTask<String,Void,JSONObject>{
    protected JSONObject doInBackground(String... params){
        /* Relevant Code 
        */
    }

    protected void onPostExecute(JSONObject result){
    variable = value; // required value being assigned to the variable
    }

}
}
```

I am getting proper value assigned to the my String Variable "variable" in the inner class, but i am not able to the access the value in my main class.

Comment: You shouldn't expose around public variables like that. Instead use a callback and use that in the inner class to trigger a method in the main class

Comment: That's because you're looking at the value before the async task has set it...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
new InnerClass().execute(params);
variable // Here the value is always null
```

You call `execute` but your main thread continue, so variable is still null because `AsyncTask.onPostExecute` was still not called.

Comment: That is not the issue. the issue is that the variable is accessed in main before it is set in the inner class

Comment: I answered with the original question, withput editing, so maybe i didnt undestand you. Sorry.

Comment: The issue in the original question was the same. I only slightly edited the question title (and changed it back afterwards)

Comment: Yap,i know, i edited my answer as soon as i could

Answer (score 0):

You use async task, it creates thread for you to execute your code. Your variable is null because your thread didn't finish his job.

Answer (score 0):

create inner class object like.

```
InnerClass inner=new InnerClass();
String name=inner.name;
```

That's it.

Answer (score 0):

If you wan result from your asynk task you can do like that:
Separate class for asynk task:

```
class InnerClass extends AsyncTask<String,Void,JSONObject>{
  protected JSONObject doInBackground(String... params){
    /* Relevant Code 
    */
  }
}
```

In your activity:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
  String variable;
  public onCreate(){

     onClickListener{
      startAsync();
     }
   }
  private void startAsync(){
         InnerClass task = new InnerClass(){

          protected void onPostExecute(JSONObject result){
              variable = value;
          }

         };
         task.execute(params);

  }
 }
```

This is only for adaptation of your code. Better way is to make long tasks in appliaction context ,and sending results to activities/ fragments by EventBus.
If you use above implementaion you have to create methods to canceling task when onDestroy is called.